# Dapper Dynamic Parameter Column or Global Variable not found

Tags: c#, dapper, dynamicparameters

I am trying to use dapper and dynamicParameters to query against an AS/400.  Any time I add DynamicParameters to my query, I get an error stating the column or global variable is not found.

This is my query: "SELECT * FROM myLib.SITECONTENT WHERE CONTENTACTIVE = @CONTENTACTIVE"

This is what my dynamic parameters look like:

[image]

This is how I'm trying to execute my query:

```
var result = conn.Query<Model.SiteContent>(query, parameters).ToList();
```

I can query in the database WHERE CONTENTACTIVE = '1' and I get results without issue.  And if I run the query without including any dynamic parameters, it works just fine also.

But when I include dynamic parameters, I get an error stating "Column or global variable @CONTENTACTIVE not found.'"

Comment: Using named parameters like `@CONTENTACTIVE` is usually only for SQL server. For AS/400, try using `SELECT * FROM myLib.SITECONTENT WHERE CONTENTACTIVE = ?`, although I'm not 100% sure how to set the parameter on the query for that syntax

Comment: That did it, thank you so much for your help!  This is my first project with the AS/400 so it's not my forte for sure.